# Swift Resetting a Constraint crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints, crashlytics

**Firebase Crashlytics** just showed this bug and I have absolutely no idea what is going on here.

[image]

This is **Line 124** in `WishlistTableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! WhishCell
    
    cell.mainStackViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0 // -> line 124
```

I am simply resetting `Constraint`. How can this fail???

This is inside my `cell`:

```
contentView.addSubview(mainStackView)

mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
mainStackViewLeadingConstraint = mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15 + 40 + 30)
mainStackViewLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Does anyone have an idea how this can crash?? If you need more code or any info just let me know. I am clueless...

Comment: You're not exactly showing how you initially set up the constraint (I'm assuming its likely a `var mainStackViewLeadingConstraint` of some sort) but it doesn't feel to me like that's the issue. (If you can move all your cell code constraints into a UIView and it works, then you're dealing with a different issue. Question - can **you** duplicate the issue? I'm wondering if this is more related to how a UITableView works more than the the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: @dfd no way I can duplicate the issue... first time this occurred. Tried everything but it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @dfd by the way this is how I init it:     `var mainStackViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!` . I mean I force unwrap it but I immediately assign it to the `constraint` so why/how can this crash in `cellForRow` ??

Comment: I honestly don't know. And yep, this sounds like I was thinking. Not easily duplicatable, quite possibly due to how a `UITableView` behaves, and...??? Here's my thoughts. (1) Keeping in mind that I don't use crashlytics, is there *anything* else to point you in the right direction? I'm thinking iOS version, number of times it's occurred, anything? (2) Think about what *really* happens with `cellForRow`. Basically (and this is likely way too simplistic) one of two things. It will either (a) create a new cell or (b) reuse one because the user is scrolling.

Comment: That - 2b - was the reason for what I was asking. It's really straightforward to *create* a table view with a set amount of cells. But if you have a table with 100 cells but only 7 are visible? Now you are at the mercy of how Apple has (purposely) designed how a `UITableView` and a `UITableViewCell` work. Constraints just add to things. From what you've posted you are doing constraints properly.

Comment: It's a bit weird how you have it set up, what's (equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15 + 40 + 30) all about? Using Auto Layout means you don't have to hack away at the UI with random values but you have done exactly that. Also why are you setting a value in cell for row and then in the cell setting a completely different value? From what I can see, in the cell it may be trying to pin the stack view to the content view before it's completely added.

Comment: @latenitecoder youre right, I don't really have to set the `constant` inside the `cell` but I a have to  set it inside `cellForRow`  because the value depends on a *status* which I check. And I have to reset it at the beginning so *reusing*  working properly. Does that make sense? what do you mean by *before it's completely added*  and how can I fix this?

Comment: I guess I'm saying, the line 124 error maybe cause by caused by the mainStackViewLeadingConstraint not being initialised or ready for use. I would put a break point on both line 124, and also within the cell where you set the constant (15+40+30) and double check that mainStackViewLeadingConstraint is not nil

Comment: @latenitecoder I can not recreate this error. It never happened to me but it happened for 2 (out of 700) users now.

Comment: What is the actual error - does crashlytics give you more info?

Comment: @latenitecoder unfortunately not.. this is everything :(

Comment: That's tough if you can't recreate the bug and it doesn't give you anything more than the line number. I'd check Xcode debugger to see if anything might give you a clue as to what's happening as it sounds like an edge case. Maybe try some fast scrolling and scrolling from top to bottom then back again as fast as you can to try and break the table.

Comment: I would first ensure that line 124 is the one that you think it is. Was it the same line 124 in  the code base that was compiled into the released version for which you see the crash? Also, in which method do you create the `mainStackViewLeadingConstraint`? It might be that it is simply `nil` due to some conditions after you dequeue the cell.